# GuiViewer3D method fitToView fails

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In version 7.93, calling the GuiViewer3D `fitToView()`.

Error message: `TypeError: can't access private field or method: object is not the right class.`

Here is the stacktrace:

[image]

On version 7.92, the method works as expected.

Comment: Are you using any specific viewer configuration, or anything out of the ordinary in your app? When I go to https://aps-simple-viewer-nodejs.autodesk.io/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cGV0cmJyb3otc2FtcGxlcy9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0 (where the viewer version is 7.93.1 at the time of writing this comment), I can call `NOP_VIEWER.fitToView([2228])` in the console successfully.

Comment: Thank you for getting back on the right track. The issue arose when storing the viewer instance inside the Vue Pinia store. It appears that this is not the appropriate location for storing the viewer instance to make it globally accessible within the app, as Pinia tracks all the changes inside the viewer. The solution was to store the viewer instance in a class static field.